# Example of image animation using only Core Graphics and CADisplayLink

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, core-graphics, cadisplaylink

I am looking for an example of an image animation (animation using images from file) done with Core Graphics and CADisplayLink (Not UIKit, CAANimation, CALayer). real low level stuff. Does anyone know of such an example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This tutorial (http://zearfoss.wordpress.com/2011/09/02/more-cadisplaylink/) shows drawing code using CADisplayLink but it should be easily adaptable to doing image animation.

Comment: My questions states "Animations using images from file". This tutorial does not address that. Thank you.